# Adding feeds from some other sites to the chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

This site has an [associated chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13591) which is frequented by some users. I wonder whether it might be useful to add some feeds from other sites to the [feeds for this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13591/mathematics-educators?tab=feeds). In this way there would be a place where such questions are easily accessible for people who mostly visit this site. (And perhaps it might also slightly increase interest in this site's chatroom.)

As an example of a room with feeds of this type, I will mention the [main chatroom on Academia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2496/the-ivory-tower?tab=feeds). If you wish to see how does this look like and whether it disturbs everyday interaction too much, you can browse a bit [through the transcript of that room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2496).

There certainly are posts related to topic of this site also on other Stack Exchange sites. I guess you can find some relevant questions among questions in [mathematics-education tag](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/mathematics-education) on MathOverflow, [teaching tag](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) on Academia
maybe also [education tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) on Mathematics.

What do you think about this suggestion? If you think that it is a reasonable idea, you might also propose some other suitable tags which could be added there.

I will add that I have asked about this [also in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13591/2017/12/8). (But no extensive discussion was held there - basically after I asked about this, the suggestion was to ask on meta.) Not too long ago I have also asked similar question [on History of Science and Mathematics Meta](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/283).

Perhaps I should also mention that the chat room [does not have a room owner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13591/mathematics-educators) at the moment. (If a room is active enough, ownership can be assigned to a user automatically, see [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80205/chat-clean-up-owner-rules/80208#80208) for details. However, this room is far from the numbers needed for that.) But moderators automatically have all privileges of room owners, in particular, they can add/remove feeds. Details what a user can do in chat - depending on the reputation and on whether the user is RO/mod - are explained here: [Is there a list of SE chat privileges, and the minimum reputation required for those privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87761)